# ajax when trying to access d[obj].src it return undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**AJAX**

```
  function ajax_json_gallery(folder) {
      alert(folder);
      var thumbnailbox = $('#thumbnailbox');
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "json_gallery_data.php",
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          dataType: "json",
          data: "folder=" + folder,
          success: function(d) {
              for (var obj in d) {
                  if (d.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
                      alert(d[obj]); //access data// 
                      alert(d[obj].src); //undefined//
                  }
              }
          }
      });
  }
```

**PHP**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$folder = "Img/Company1/Jersey1";
$dir = $folder."/";
$dirHandle = opendir($dir); 
$i = 0;
$directoryfiles = array();
while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    if(!is_dir($file) && preg_match("/.jpg|.gif|.png/i", $file)){
        $i++;
        $src = "$dir$file";
$directoryfiles[] = '"img'.$i.'":{ "num":"'.$i.'","src":"'.$src.'", "name":"'.$file.'" },';
    }
}
closedir($dirHandle);

echo json_encode($directoryfiles);
```

**console.log(d)**

```
[""img1":{ "num":"1","src":"Img/House1/Type1/Image1.png", "name":"Image1.png" },", 
    ""img2":{ "num":"2","src":"Img/House1/Type1/Image2.png", "name":"Image2.png" },", 
    ""img3":{ "num":"3","src":"Img/House1/Type1/Image3.png", "name":"Image3.png" },", 
    ""img4":{ "num":"4","src":"Img/House1/Type1/Image4.png", "name":"Image4.png" },"]
```

**x3**

i am using ajax to get all image inside the folder directory , and return to ajax but when i tried to access the d[o].src it return undefined ,i had no idea what am i missing here.

Comment: Those extra quotation marks in the array are killing me. I'm assuming that is the issue.  If you're using `json_encode` when echoing out the response, why do you build a json string? Why not build a php `array` and let `json_encode` handle the formatting?

Comment: like how? could you give me a sample?

Comment: Patrick Evans' answer below is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: got it , thank you too~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to write JSON text yourself. Just create an associative array or stdClass object, add the appropriate key/values, then add that to `$directoryfiles`. `json_encode` will then do the proper encoding

```
$directoryfiles = array();
while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    if(!is_dir($file) && preg_match("/.jpg|.gif|.png/i", $file)){
        $i++;
        $src = "$dir$file";
        $temp = new stdClass;
        $temp->num = $i;
        $temp->src = $src;
        $temp->name = $file;
        $directoryfiles["img".$i] = $temp;
    }
}
closedir($dirHandle);

echo json_encode($directoryfile);
```

Comment: thank you , there is really something wrong on my JSON written , but this give me a big help and improven you.

Answer (score 0):

change the format of json to,

```
{"img1":{ "num":"1","src":"Img/House1/Type1/Image1.png", "name":"Image1.png" }, 
 "img2":{ "num":"2","src":"Img/House1/Type1/Image2.png", "name":"Image2.png" }, 
 "img3":{ "num":"3","src":"Img/House1/Type1/Image3.png", "name":"Image3.png" }, 
 "img4":{ "num":"4","src":"Img/House1/Type1/Image4.png", "name":"Image4.png" }};
```

then u use the code,

```
console.log(d.img1.src);
```